# Why is it asking for self.init to be called, when I have added self.init(url: url)?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, initialization, network-protocols

So I get the error 'self.init' isn't called on all paths before return from initializer. Though I am confused to what that may be because I have added self.init(url: url) after initializing URLComponents for the url to be passed in. Then use URLRequest properties to make a request. But why is it still giving me this error? Is there something I missed? Would be helpful to know the reason why. Thank you.

```
import Foundation

extension URLRequest {

    init(service: ServiceProtocol) {

        guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(service: service),
            let url = urlComponents.url else {
            return
        }

        self.init(url: url)

        httpMethod = service.method.rawValue
        service.headers?.forEach { key, value in
            addValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)
        }

        guard case let .requestParameters(parameters) = service.task, service.parametersEncoding == .json else {
            return
        }

        httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means if the url object is never successfully created, the required initializer is never called — which is forbidden.

You could make your init throw an error in the else statement or the guard.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick.  I made it so init throws, just as you said, and composed an enum named (URLError: Error) that subclasses the Error protocol and inside the else statement of guard let I just did "throw URLError.unableToComposeURL"